# Reduce time complexity while traversing dataset

Tags: c#, .net, time-complexity

I have  a dataset with *n* number of datatables. Minimum value for *n* is 30.
In each datatable, the first row defines the datatype of the data in the following rows. For example:

```
string  Integer  string  Integer  Integer
test1    67      test1   45       78
test2    45      test1   32       45
```

There can be any number of rows, and I need to validate that the data matches the defined datatype. For example, test1 is a string, 67 is a integer, etc.

I need to do this validation for the entire dataset.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
foreach(DataTable dt in dataset.Tables)
{
 for(int iRow = 1; iRow <dt.Rows.Count; iRow ++)
    { 
     for(int jCol = 0;jCol< dt.Columns.Count;jCol++)
      {
       //Datatype validation check
      }
    }
}
```

This solution works fine. The time complexity is O(datatablescount * dtrowscount * dtcolumnscount). I am trying to optimize the code and looking for any pointers to reduce the time complexity.

Comment: if you need to check all dat, you have to check it, and complexity can not be reduced

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to help. Without knowing the actual computation you're doing we can't optimize.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do t*r*c checks then that's how many you can check. I'd recommend trying to reduce the constant time factors and accept the complexity.

One way to decrease constant time: If you tell C# what the datatype of the column should be it will check the type for you when you put data in the datatable.

For example:

```
// Will require that all values inserted in this column can be converted to Int32
dt.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(Int32);
```

Another thing you can do is check less columns.